# why am I getting a "'int' object is not subscriptable" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
y = []
x = 1
a = 1
count = 0
count2 = 1
while x == 1:
    z = int(input("input: " ))
    if z < 0:
        x = 0
    y.append(z)
length = len(y)
while a == 1:
    if z[count] > z[count2]:
        z[count], z[count+1] = z[count+1], z[count]
        count = count + 1
    if count == lenth:
        a = 0
```

I get it at the `if z[count] > z[count2]:` part of the code.

Comment: Change `lenth` to 'length' in line 17.

Answer (score 2):

`z` is an integer (taken from user input). You probably wanted to use `y` instead, the list to which you append `z`:

```
if y[count] > y[count2]:
    y[count], y[count+1] = y[count+1], y[count]
```

Comment: This is why you give your variables meaningful names rather than `x` `y` and `z` (unless those are, say, coordinates and therefore meaningful).

Answer (score 1):

You declare `z` as an `int`

```
z = int(input("input: " ))
```

Then you try to index it

```
if z[count] > z[count2]:
```

And exactly as the error says, you cannot index an `int`, that operation has no meaning.

I'm assuming you meant this?

```
if y[count] > y[count2]:
```

Comment: Thank you. i have noew seen the light. i was just being an idiot. been working for so long :c

Comment: Minor nit: Python doesn't have variable declarations; you are assigning an `int` object to the name `z`.

Comment: @chepner I'm a C++ programmer for a living. I often find myself using C++ terminology when explaining Python concepts, although they frequently (as in this case) are not exactly the same. My context switching could use some work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
z[count] > z[count2]
```

Here `z` is an integer as `z = int(input("input: " ))` will give you an Integer